# (wordpress) Вывести список всех онлайн пользователей кроме одного

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Всем привет! Мне нужно вывести список пользователей залогиненых в данный момент на сайте, кроме пользователя с user_id=1 и user_name=guest.
Подскажите как это сделать. 
Вывожу список пользователей таким кодом:

```
<?php
$users_online = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_name, user_id FROM wp_useronline");

// Echo the title of the first scheduled post
if ($users_online) {
    foreach ($users_online as $user_online) {
       echo $user_online->user_name . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Не могу правильно составить условие, чтобы отфильтровывать user_id 1 и user_name Guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отфильтровать пользователей лучше при выборке из бд, указав условие

```
SELECT user_name, user_id FROM wp_useronline WHERE user_id != 1 AND user_name != 'guest'
```

Если по каким-то причинам вы не хотите изменять sql запрос, то в цикле укажите условие

```
foreach ($users_online as $user_online) { 
 if($user_online->user_id != 1 and $user_online->user_name != 'guest')
  echo $user_online->user_name . "\n"; 
}
```